# PhpStorm cannot "Synchronize all" despite mapping configured

Tags: phpstorm

I am facing an issue with PhpStorm: I don't have access to "Synchronize all" button in compare window.

[image: screenshot of issue]

However, I can still upload to my server using direct menu :

[image: Direct upload menu]

Also if I add `/.idea` in deployment excluded path then it will exclude everything even if it's not inside `/idea`. I have to remove unselected filter to show my files...

[image: Hide filter]

It's not really convenient and I don't know what went wrong. Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: 1) Sounds like you have not marked any server as Default for this project. Please try that first. 2) You do not need to do anything with `.idea` subfolder. It never gets in a way (but then, I do not sync whole project root: only folders that needed (e.g. `app`, `config`. etc; why sync files that are needed for my local dev only)).

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer ! 1) I got sure that there was a default server set in settings. 2) `.idea` folder is also synchronised unless it is marked as excluded in deployment settings (which I do, there is an distant app folder but no local one). 3) I went to `settings > directories` and redefined everything as it should. It fixed my issue but I couldn't think of it without your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to comment of @LazyOne I could solve my problem.

I went into `settings > directories` and redefined root folder for my project. Then I could access to synchronize all.

Note that you need a default server to be able to sync.